# clearing a kml from google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a google map and I am wanting to show this KML file, I can load the KML but I haven't yet figured out how to clear it off the map.  I load the KML on the map when the user click a check box, but whe they uncheck the box the KML wont go away.   Here is the code that I am using to load the KML.

```
var isShowData = false;
//showEMSz(null);
var tileEMSz;
function showEMSz(obj) {
    isShowData = !isShowData;

    if (isShowData) {

        tileEMSz = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: '/ELTSCAD.kml'
    });
    tileEMSz.setMap(map);
  }
else 
{
    // remove Option
    tileEMSz = null;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `map`-property of the layer to null:

```
if(tileEMSz){tileEMSz.setMap(null);}
```